# Django filter similar to postgre bigint[]

Tags: django, django-models

I have a column - > items_ids which is postgre bigint[]

So i can have items_ids as [ 34L,23L, 45L, 32L] or [23L, 43L, 34L, 33L] and so on .

So my question is how can I use filter for all rows containing say 33L.

I used `Mymodels.objects.filter(item_ids__icontain = 23L)`

But does not seems to work.

How can i change my query.

thanks..

Comment: I did't get you ?? have you tried with out "L"

Answer (score 0):

remove L from filter and try

```
Mymodels.objects.filter(item_ids__icontain = 23)
```

and this should work